# Get a group of numbers from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a file that contains strings, which in turn contain numbers of 10 digits. I need to extract the numbers, with regex and put them in an array.
I think I can use `\d{10}` but I'm not sure how to actually apply that with Java.

Also, an additional element of complexity, is potentially if there are a lot of numbers there may be multiple numbers with different forms like `123456745-9` and `123456745-95` signifying a range. I'd like to extract those numbers as well. (I can handle creating the range of numbers in java, Regex is not necessary for that)

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you want the contents of the final array to be? Integers? Strings?

Also, will 123456745-9 indicate 5 unique numbers (123456745, 123456746, ..., 123456749) or what? If so, those aren't 10 digits.

How is the file organized? By lines? Is it records of something? Does each line only contain one 10-digit number?

Comment: suppose i have bla bla bla 123456789 bla bla 123456789 bla bla 123456765-9 bla bla bla 123456767-89 bla bla
 from the above i want to get [123456789, 123456789,123456765-9, 123456767-89]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split on non-digit characters but keep the `-`:

```
String[] numbers = input.split("[^\\-\\d]+");
```

Example:

```
String input = "bla bla bla 123456789 bla bla 123456789 bla bla 123456765-9 bla bla bla 123456767-89 bla bla";
input = input.replaceFirst("^[^\\-\\d]*", ""); //remove the leading non-digits if any
String[] numbers = input.split("[^\\-\\d]+"); //split
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

outputs:

```
[123456789, 123456789, 123456765-9, 123456767-89]
```

Comment: this looks like it might be what i need. i'll have to test it out. thanks!

Comment: @Lemonio I have amended to use the example you gave in the comments.

Comment: thanks for the clear and thorough response! i'll try to do the rest of the java myself now

Answer (score 0):

The regex is simpler than you think. You just need to match any digit one or more times.

Example:

```
String line = "a line with some digits 123456745-9 and maybe some more 343-34 and a single 1 99 ";
String regexpattern = "(\\d+)(-(\\d+))?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexpattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("number= '" + matcher.group(1)+"'");
    if (matcher.group(3) != null)
        System.out.println("range '" + matcher.group(3)+"'");
}
```

This output would be the following

```
number= '123456745'
ranges to '9'
number= '343'
ranges to '34'
number= '1'
number= '99'
```

Comment: would it be possible to keep the numbers with the - together? otherwise it will be hard for me to keep track which ones go together

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response.  You already have your answer but for completeness I added what you were looking for into the answer